# window.onerror getting an empty url?

Tags: javascript

What would cause window.onerror to receive an empty url parameter?
A client is getting JS errors every 16 seconds and my logs show the error has no url.
Is this likely from a plugin?
Is it safe to ignore errors from window.onerror that have an empty URL?

This is happening in safari for the record, and I don't have access to the computer

```
webkit: true
version: 537.36
safari: true
Netscape 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: if it's a script included on page, I think you wouldn't get an URL

Comment: Errors do not normally return URLs. Why are you expecting one?

Comment: Zathrus: I am definitely seeing urls in external js files, but I am not sure about in-page code. Maybe you are right. I thought it would return the page URL though?

Comment: Diodeus: The mozilla docs state a URL on window.onerror https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fwindow.onerror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have figured it out using this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/Mza9X/

It seems that errors occurring in setTimeout cause an empty URL in window.onerror
The second link, when clicked
It might also be the case for setInterval

```
<a href="#" onclick="gsegsge.segseg">Click me</a>
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout('segse.segseg', 1000);">Click me2</a>

<script>
    window.onerror = function(one, two, three) {
    alert(two);
    alert(arguments[1]);
    }
</script>
```

Where it's actually coming from in my case is still unknown since there should be nothing that is supposed to act like this...    :P